# Ubuntu ffmpeg command -i not found

Tags: video, configuration, ffmpeg

I'm a beginner with Ubuntu and I need to setup a streaming server for my company, I've installed NGINX and FFMPEG, but when I call `ffmpeg -i` in the `~/ffmpeg/ffmpeg` directory it returns an error `command not found` but when I call `./ffmpeg -i` it returns a list with configurations.. why does `ffmpeg -i` not work and how can I fix it?

I think that the `Path Enviroment Variable is incorrect` but how would I go abouts changing said variable? I'm not that experienced with Ubuntu / CMD programming / FFMPEG configuration.

Sources - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu
https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Control-module
and http://docs.unified-streaming.com/tutorials/live/broadcast-247.html#continuous-timestamps

Comment: What if you do `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`? Also, you can just add `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/ffmpeg/executable` into your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I've tried the export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/ffmpeg/executable but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I hope you replaced `/path/to/ffmpeg/executable` with the *actual* path to the `ffmpeg` executable?

Comment: Yes I have, I moved this question over from SO

Comment: Try `/path/to/ffmpeg/directory`, as @terdon suggested.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? How did you install `ffmpeg`? If you followed a guide please provide the link. It is likely you will not need to use `export` or edit `~/.profile`, or mess with anything like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a directory to my path?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the directory where you've installed `ffmpeg` to your `$PATH`, the list of directories where executables can be found. The simplest way is to add this line to your `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/ffmpeg
```

Note that you need to add the directory containing the `ffmpeg` executable and not the executable itself. Then, log out and log back in again (or just run `. ~/.profile`) and you should be able to execute it from anywhere.